# Validation on Text Entry

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a validation function that has the conditions of it being a number and greater than zero. I can do it in python but now I'm trying to use entry boxes in tkinter it appears to be more difficult. I have included the code I have got so far.

```
from tkinter import *


class quote():  
def __init__(self, master):

    self.master=master

    self.master.title("Quote Screen")
    self.master.geometry("2100x1400")

    self.master.configure(background = "white")
    self.Borras = PhotoImage(file = "Borras.Logo.2.gif") #sets up image
    self.Borras.image = self.Borras
    self.BorrasLabel = Label(self.master, image = self.Borras, bg = "white")#puts image onto label
    self.BorrasLabel.place(anchor=NW)

    self.Title = Label(self.master, text = "New Quote", font = ("calibri", 20), bg = "White")
    self.Title.place(x=650, y = 10)

    self.SubmitButton = PhotoImage(file = "Submit.Button.gif") #sets up image
    self.SubmitButton.image = self.SubmitButton
    self.SubmitButtonLabel = Button(self.master, image = self.SubmitButton, bg = "white", command= self.Validation)#puts image onto a button
    self.SubmitButtonLabel.place(x=900, y=290)

    global PostCodeValue
    global HeightValue
    global LengthValue
    global PitchValue
    global RiseValue

    PostCodeVar = StringVar() 
    PostCodeEntry = Entry(master,width=50, font=20, textvariable=PostCodeVar)
    PostCodeEntry.place(x = 20, y = 150)
    PostCodeVar.set("Please enter the Post Code")
    PostCodeValue = PostCodeVar.get()

    HeightVar = StringVar() 
    HeightEntry = Entry(master, width=50, font=20, textvariable=HeightVar)
    HeightEntry.place(x = 20, y = 220)
    HeightVar.set("Please enter the Height") 
    HeightValue = HeightVar.get() 

    LengthVar = StringVar()
    LengthEntry = int(Entry(master, width=50, font=20, textvariable=LengthVar))
    LengthEntry.place(x = 20, y = 290)
    LengthVar.set("Please enter the Length")
    LengthValue = LengthVar.get() 

    PitchVar = StringVar() 
    PitchEntry = Entry(master, width=50, font=20, textvariable=PitchVar)
    PitchEntry.place(x = 20, y = 360)
    PitchVar.set("Please enter the Pitch") 
    PitchValue = PitchVar.get() 

    RiseVar = StringVar() 
    RiseEntry = Entry(master, width=50, font=20, textvariable=RiseVar)
    RiseEntry.place(x = 20, y = 430)
    RiseVar.set("Please enter the Rise") 
    RiseValue = RiseVar.get()



def Validation(self):
    if LengthValue > 0 and LengthValue.isdigit():
        print('well done')
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: How is this question different than the other question you asked about validation?

Comment: Here i am looking how to check the data, for example to make sure it is an integer between 0 and 360.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string is a number by simply trying to convert it to a number:

```
try:
    pitch = int(PitchVar.get())
    print("it is an integer")
except ValueError:
    print("it is NOT an integer")
```

Once you convert it, you can simply compare it to the range of numbers you're interested in:

```
try:
    pitch = int(PitchVar.get())
    if pitch < 0 or pitch > 360:
        print("Not between 0 and 360")
except ValueError:
    print("it is NOT an integer")
```

---

note: you don't need to use those special variables (`PitchVar`, `PostCodevar`, etc). You can get the value from the entry widget by calling the `get` method of the widget itself, and put values into the entry widget with `set()`:

```
PitchEntry = Entry(...)
PitchEntry.insert(0, "Please enter the Pitch")

pitch = int(PitchEntry.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a `try / except` you can take advantage of how python handles if statements and use something like this instead.

```
def Validation(self):
    if LengthVar.get().isdigit() and 0 < int(LengthVar.get()) < 360:
        print('Well Done')
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Here python first checks if `LengthValue` is a digit. If true it goes on the the next condition. If false it will stop there and move to the else.

Another option to the `try / except` method that Bryan suggested is you can assert if the value is between 0 and 360. This way you can do something else in that case.

```
def Validation(self):
    try:
        pitch = int(PitchVar.get())
        assert 0 < pitch < 360 # if value is not between 0 and 360 AssertionError is raised
    except ValueError:
        print("it is NOT an integer")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Not between 0 and 360")
```

**Side Notes**

By having this assignment in your `__init__` function, `LengthValue` will always be the initial value.

```
LengthValue = LengthVar.get()
```

In your case it's `LengthVar.set("Please enter the Length")`.
You should always get the value when you need to use it, so it's the current value.

Having said this. The only widget that needs a variable assigned is the `OptionMenu` widget. everything else you can get the value as a string using `Widget.get()`. Which looks like `LengthEntry.get()`